# Convert tuple into dict and choose dict key names

Tags: python

I have the following tuple:
`(1234234, 23, 0)`

I would like to make it into a dict of the following form:

```
{
  app: 1234234,
  sdk: 23,
  done: 0,
}
```

How can that be achieved?

update: This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706935/how-can-i-take-two-tuples-to-produce-a-dictionary) as it is not implied that it could only be solved by using two tuples.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take two tuples to produce a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706935/how-can-i-take-two-tuples-to-produce-a-dictionary)

Comment: "choose key names" -- How? Ask the user to enter key names? Read the key names from a file? Use predefined constants as key names?

Comment: ``dict(zip(('app', 'sdk', 'done'), (123423434, 23, 0)))``

Answer (score 3):

Something like the below

```
values = (1234234, 23, 0)
keys = ['app', 'sdk', 'done']
d = {k: values[idx] for idx, k in enumerate(keys)}
print(d)
```

output

```
{'app': 1234234, 'sdk': 23, 'done': 0}
```

Comment: Nice. Alternatively, you can use `zip`. See my below answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach from @balderman:

```
values = (1234234, 23, 0)
keys = ['app', 'sdk', 'done']
d = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = (1234234, 23, 0)
keys = ["app", "sdk", "done"]
d = {}

for num in t:
    key = keys[t.index(num)]
    d[key] = num
```

This code will iterate over the numbers in a tuple and assign the keys in order to the numbers within the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**a)** if you want to chose the keys manually (user input via shell) you can do:

```
values = (1234234, 23, 0)
yourdict = {input(f"insert key fot value {value}: "): value for value in values}
```

output:

```
>>> insert a key for value 1234234: value1
>>> insert a key for value 23: value2
>>> insert a key for value 0: value3

{"value1": 1234234, "value2": 23, "value3": 0}
```

**b)** if you want to do it automatically from a list of keys:

```
values = (1234234, 23, 0)
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
yourdict = {keys[count]: value for count, value in enumerate(values)}
```

output:

```
{"key1": 1234234, "key2": 23, "key3": 0}
```

**c)** if you want to assign them numerically:

```
values = (1234234, 23, 0)
yourdict = {count: value for count, value in enumerate(values)}
```

output:

```
{0: 1234234, 1: 23, 2: 0}
```