# Tuples to dictionary , where first tuple are keys and second tuple is corresponding elements?

Tags: python

need a function that takes in two tuples and returns a dictionary in which
the elements of the first tuple are used as keys, and the corresponding elements of the second

for example, calling `tuples_to_dict(('a','b', 'c', 'a'), (1,2,3,4))`
will return `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}`

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in zip(tuple1, tuple2)}` or `dict(zip(tuple1, tuple2))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take two tuples to produce a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706935/how-can-i-take-two-tuples-to-produce-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

you could use `dict` with `zip` method:

- `zip()` to merge two or more iterables into tuples of two.
- `dict()` function creates a dictionary.

```py
def tuples_to_dict(x,y):
    return dict(zip(x,y))
```

*result*
{'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

Other way using `enumerate` and *dictionary comprehension*:

```py
def tuples_to_dict(x,y):
    return {x[i]:y[i] for i,_ in enumerate(x)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you needed it to not insert the second 'a' you can check prior to inserting the value and not do so if already present:

```py
def tuples_to_dict(first, second):
    out = {}
    for k, v in zip(first, second):
        if k not in out:
            out[k] = v
    return out

tuples_to_dict(('a','b', 'c', 'a'), (1,2,3,4))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```